# Opening a link in the browser?

Tags: android, file, browser, web, kml

I have been trying to use an intent to open a link to a kml file using the browser. That way when it goes to the link it will download and open the file in Google Maps (or Google Earth). However, when I click on it in the emulator nothing seems to happen. Any ideas?

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class dl_viewKML
{
    void downloadFile()
    {
        String encodedURL = "http://" + "www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/data.kml";

        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(encodedURL));
        startActivity(webIntent);

    }

    private void startActivity(Intent webIntent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Eclipse doesn't show up any problems and it doesn't show up anything in LogCat.

Comment: What information do you want? It doesn't do anything at all. I click the button that calls this function and it doesn't do anything. Nothing appears in LogCat and nothing appears in the Console. It's as if I didn't didn't even click the button. Why won't it open this link?

Comment: Did you ensure that its actually going into that method via a log?

Comment: Could be perhaps because the `startActivity(...)` method in your `dl_viewKML` class doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Is this better?

<code>
public class dl_viewKML
{
 String encodedURL = "http://" + "www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/data.kml";

 void downloadFile()
 {
  Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     startActivity(webIntent);
  
 }

 private void startActivity(Intent webIntent)
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Uri.parse(encodedURL);
  
 }
}
</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the method [`startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) to start your `Intent` you have to either call it from the class or subclasses(like Activity, FragmentActivity) of [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) or get a reference to the context and call it.

Because your class `dl_viewKML` isn't a subclass of `Context` you have to get a reference to the context. You can do this by adding a constructor with a `Context` parameter like in this:

```
package shc_BalloonSat.namespace;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class dl_viewKML {
private Context ctx

public dl_viewKML(Context ctx) {
this.ctx = ctx;
}
    void downloadFile()
    {
        String encodedURL = "http://" + "www.wktechnologies.com/shc_android_app/data.kml";

        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(encodedURL));
        ctx.startActivity(webIntent);

    }

}
```

In your `Activity` where you instantiate the `dl_viewKML` class you will do something like this:

```
dl_viewKML obj = new dl_viewKML(this);
```

or

```
dl_viewKML obj = new dl_viewKML(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: thanks that got it working. Now if I can just figure out how to open it in Google Maps instead of displaying the text in a browser.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted i don't have experience with Google Maps but try to replace `Uri.parse(encodedURL)`  with Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + encodedURL)